# JQuery and JavaScript working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to know can we apply jQuery on JavaScript objects.

I had few images declared in JavaScript and I want to apply jQuery to give some nice effects, I read somewhere that jQuery produces different sought of objects and to apply jQuery I had to declare my image as div class or in css. Is it true?

Comment: Your question makes no sense whatsoever.  I recommend that you read the jQuery documentation.

Comment: You're going to have to do a better job at explaining your question, give some example code at least.

Comment: It sounds like you just want to start with some basic jQuery tutorials: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials

Comment: are you from **big bang theory**?

Comment: ohh u now know the secret that im raj from Big Bang theory...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to a CSS selector, jQuery's `$` function can also take a DOM element.

Comment: <img id="image" src="smiley.gif" width="160" height="120">

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("image").src="landscape.jpg";
</script>

<p>The original image was smiley.gif, but the script changed it to landscape.jpg</p>